# Sifr Wordpress Plugin: disable for IE6?

Tags: sifr3

I have the sifr wordpress plugin running on a site that works great. However in IE6 for a heading in the body, when sifr is on, it puts a big padding/margin on top of the heading...like 150px or so.

Since I don't have an actual IE6 install, I've been previewing at Adobe Browser Lab.

I'd like to keep sifr on these headings for real browsers and just disable this one headline style for IE6 or all sifr rendering for IE6 in the plugin. Is this possible?

I found a note in documentation about disabling in the standard sifr.js, but I cannot locate the attribute in the sifr.js for Wordpress.

!sIFR.UA.bIsIEMac (I'd like to change it to something like !sIFR.UA.bIsIE6)

The Wordpress plugin edit runs all of the code together as does Dreamweaver and TextEdit, making it tough to find the spot to make this edit.

Answer (score 0):

I would try replacing the plugin's compressed sifr.js with a [full version of the same build](http://dev.novemberborn.net/sifr3/nightlies/sifr3-r436.zip).  Then you could just add this before the sIFR.activate() call:

```
sIFR.ua.supported = sIFR.ua.supported && (!sIFR.ua.ie || sIFR.ua.ieVersion > 6);
```

To solve your no local IE install problem, you could check out the [evolt browser archives](http://browsers.evolt.org/?ie).  Nothing worse than trying to code for a browser you don't have installed...